Display bmp image using u-boot on virtual QEMU
I have an issue of displaying a bmp image using u-boot on virtual QEMU. I've built QEMU using buildroot and added the following options in u-boot.fragement file to support splash screen and virtio gpu:
CONFIG_CMD_BMP=y
CONFIG_DM_VIDEO=y
CONFIG_VIDEO=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_BMP_RLE8=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_BMP_LOGO=y
CONFIG_SPLASH_SCREEN=y
CONFIG_SPLASH_SOURCE=y
CONFIG_SPLASH_SCREEN_ALIGN=y
CONFIG_SYS_WHITE_ON_BLACK=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_LOGO=y
CONFIG_DISPLAY=y
CONFIG_VIDEO_IPUV3=y
CONFIG_BMP_8BPP=y
CONFIG_BMP_16BPP=y
CONFIG_BMP_24BPP=y
CONFIG_BMP_32BPP=y
CONFIG_PANEL=y
CONFIG_BACKLIGHT=y
CONFIG_DRM=y
CONFIG_DRM_VIRTIO_GPU=y

I've built using qemu_arm_ebbr_defconfig and started QEMU like following:
qemu-system-arm   -M virt,secure=on  
\-bios output/images/flash.bin -cpu cortex-a15  
\-device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0  
\-device virtio-net-device,netdev=eth0  
\-device virtio-rng-device,rng=rng0  
\-drive file=output/images/disk.img,if=none,format=raw,id=hd0 -netdev user,id=eth0 
\-object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng0 
\-m 2048 -smp 2 
\-device virtio-gpu-pci,xres=1680,yres=1050 -display sdl -vnc :0 -serial stdio

The thing is that when I interrupt autoboot to get to u-boot prompt, the display window that pops up show this: 
And when I use bmp display <addr> command with a valid bmp image, nothing is shown. It's important to mention, that if I let it autoboot, boot logs are displayed and I think kernel is initializing the display. I've tried searching about initializing the display from u-boot, but unfortunately found nothing.
I've also tried different type of display, gtk for example and different types of device except form virtio-gpu-pci, -ramfb for example, but it did not help. Does anyone has any idea why it is behaving like this? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks

There is no CONFIG_DRM=y and CONFIG_DRM_VIRTIO_GPU=y into the u-boot configurations
